# RxJS ShareReplay and PublishReplay

Tags: angular, rxjs6

I understand the difference between ShareReplay and PublishReplay but in my following example I could use some clarification why a PublishReplay shortly after a previous PublishReplay does not emit any events but ShareReplay does.

I have an Angular service which provides some API data to several components. I use publishReplay to multicast the data to the components without refetching the data several times, and it is cleaned up once all of the components unsubscribe.

```
@Injectable()
export class APIService {

  data = this.http.get(url).pipe(
      publishReplay(1)
  );
}
```

The components build FormControls once they receive the data event, and still use the raw data in the html hence the tap

```
@Component()
export class SomeComponent {

  data = this.apiService.data.pipe(
      tap((data) => buildControls(data))
  );
}
```

In a few instances I need to create some observables from the formControls after they have been built. I need to multicast this otherwise the formControls are rebuilt on each subsequent subscription and don't bind properly.

```
@Component()
export class SomeComponent {

  data = this.apiService.data.pipe(
      tap((data) => buildControls(data)),
      shareReplay(1) // PublishReplay does not work here
  );

  someObservable = this.data.pipe(
    switchMap(() => buildLinkedControls())
  );
}
```

In the component example above, why does PublishReplay not fire any events, yet shareReplay does. Is there any danger to using shareReplay here, since the buffer will live on?

For completeness below is an simple example of the html

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(data | async)?.properties as props">
   <input *ngIf="props?.someInput" [formControl]="formGroup.get('someInput')">
    ...
   <div>{{ someObservable | async }}</div?
</ng-container>
```

Comment: What do you mean by is there any danger to using shareReplay here? Are you talking about memory leaks? By the way `shareReplay` is the correct operator here by what you are describing.